# 'function' object has no attribute 'Bootstrap'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Code:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

bs = cross_validate.Bootstrap(9, random_state=0)
```

Error:

```
'function' object has no attribute 'Bootstrap'
```

Answer (score 3):

That method was [deprecated in 2014 (v0.15)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.15.html#api-changes-summary), and was [removed in 2016 (v0.17)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.17.html#api-changes-summary).

You should use [`KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) or [`ShuffleSplit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html).